# Whay my Enum property be changed in http-response?

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core

I have a `web-service` and have this code:

```
roomStay = new RoomStay
            {
                PlaceType = stay.hotelInfo.propertyType,
                GeneralDescription = GenerateGeneralDescription(stay.hotelInfo).Result,
                IsRefundableRoom = !stay.nonRefundable,
                ProviderType = Supplier.BetterBooking,
                BasicPropertyInfo = new BasicPropertyInfo
                {
                    SupplierCode = stay.hotelInfo?.hotelName + stay.hotelInfo?.areaName
                                                          ,
                    Images = imageList,
                    NewImages = newImageList.ToArray()
                                                          ,
                    Address = $"{area + address + city + countryName  }" //$"{hotelStaticDataResult.hotelInfo?.address?.countryName} {hotelStaticDataResult.hotelInfo?.address?.cityName} {string.Join(" ", hotelStaticDataResult.hotelInfo?.address?.addressLines.ToArray())}"
                                                          ,
                    City = ""//cityName
                                                          ,
                    Name = stay.hotelInfo.hotelName
                                                          ,
                    Facilities = new List<FacilityCategory>()//facilitieList
                                                            ,
                    Longitude = longitude//hotelStaticDataResult.hotelInfo?.position.longitude
                                                            ,
                    Latitude = latitude// hotelStaticDataResult.hotelInfo?.position.latitude
                                                            ,
                    Telephone = string.Empty//hotelStaticDataResult?.hotelInfo?.contactNumbers?.Where(a => a.phoneType == "Phone").FirstOrDefault()?.phoneNumber
                                                            ,
                    Description = string.Empty,
                    TextItems = stay.hotelInfo?.textItems.Select(a => new TextItemsModelOTA()
                    {
                        Title = a.title == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.title) ? string.Empty : a.title,
                        Description = a.description == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.description) ? string.Empty : a.description,
                        TitleEnumType = (TitleEnumType)Utility.GetEnum<TitleEnumType>(a.title).Result
                    })//hotelStaticDataResult.hotelInfo?.textItems.ToJson()
                                                            ,
                    Code = hotelKey// searchrs.Result.transactionId + "$" + searchrs.Result.searchId + "$" + stay.stayId + "$" + stay.hotelInfo.hotelName
                                                            ,
                    RateProviderKeyValues = new List<RateProviderKeyValue>() { new RateProviderKeyValue() { Key = decimal.Parse(stay.hotelInfo.starRating.ToStringSafe()), Value = RateProvider.AAA } }.ToArray()

                },
                RoomRates = roomRate
                                                ,
            };
```

In the `TextItem` property, I have TextEnumType property that this type is enum like:

```
public enum TitleEnumType
    {
        Facilities = 0,
        Rooms = 1,
        Meals = 2,
        Payment = 3,
        PropertyDescription = 4,
        NumberOfRooms = 5,
        CheckInTime = 6,
        CheckOutTime = 7,
        HotelRemarks = 8,
        None = 9
    }
```

With tow method that are below, I get the string with `GetStringForEnum(string model)` method and convert to `Enum` using `GetEnum<T>(string model)` like:

```
public static int GetEnum<T>(string model)
    {
        var newModel = GetStringForEnum(model);

        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), newModel))
        {
            return (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), "None", true);

        }

        return (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), newModel, true);
    }

    private static string GetStringForEnum(string model)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
        var nonAlphanumericData = rgx.Matches(model);
        if (nonAlphanumericData.Count < 0)
        {
            return model;
        }
        foreach (var item in nonAlphanumericData)
        {
            model = model.Replace((string)item, "");
        }
        return model;
    }
```

**Note:** the `GetEnum<T>(string model)` method generate enum as true.

After my `roomStay` model be generated and before send this `roomStay` `http-response` all of my data is correct. but when I receive this `roomStay` in my website and `controller`, this `roomStay` is not correct.

What is my problem?

Comment: What value do you have in a.title?

Comment: @AlexRiabov is string, and the value is like: "Description data" - "room-list" or something like that.

Comment: And how do you expect it to be converted to your enum?

Comment: @AlexRiabov With "GetEnum<T>()" method, this is in my question.

Comment: but "Description data" - "room-list" doesn't match any of enum values

Comment: @AlexRiabov Yeah I know, I make an fake example for you, my string data is the exactly the same of my Enum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181096/discussion-between-alex-riabov-and-amirreza-farahlagha).

Comment: @AmirReza-Farahlagha Whatever you do to solve your original problem, please consider following mac's answer and making your helper methods synchronous.

Comment: @Alireza I'll check this issue.Thanks.

Comment: Don't use Task or Task<T> for operation which always perform sync. `Task.Run` does no good for the scalability and performance of your ASP.NET Core application. Rule of thumb, use async in ASP.NET Core only when its an **I/O** operation not for cpu bound operations

Answer (score 1):

It's because the method you are calling to get the enum is asynchronous. So at the time you return your RoomStay object the TextItems.TitleEnumType is the default of 0. Try:

```
public static GetEnum<T>(string model)
    {
            var newModel = GetStringForEnum(model);

            if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), newModel.Result))
            {
                var test1 = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), "None", true);
                return test1;
            }

            var test = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), newModel.Result, true);
            return test;
    }

    private static GetStringForEnum(string model)
    {
            Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
            var nonAlphanumericData = rgx.Matches(model);
            if (nonAlphanumericData.Count < 0)
            {
                return model;
            }
            foreach (var item in nonAlphanumericData)
            {
                model = model.Replace((string)item, "");
            }
            return model;
    }
```

Comment: Why can't we call it asynchronously?

Comment: You can, but in the user's scenario it sounds like this is the reason for the result they are getting. Can't know without seeing the rest of the code

Comment: @AlexRiabov Why should this code be written as async? It's processor bound and not I/O boud. Not a good candidate for async.

Comment: @mac `(TitleEnumType)Utility.GetEnum<TitleEnumType>(a.title).Result` makes it synchronous

Comment: @Alireza there is no need for this code to be async. But the problem is different here.